# PySpark RDD with Typed List convert to DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have an RDD in the following format:

```
 [(1, 
 (Rating(user=1, product=3, rating=0.99), 
  Rating(user=1, product=4, rating=0.91),  
  Rating(user=1, product=9, rating=0.68))),   
  (2, 
 (Rating(user=2, product=11, rating=1.01), 
  Rating(user=2, product=12, rating=0.98), 
  Rating(user=2, product=45, rating=0.97))), 
  (3, 
 (Rating(user=3, product=23, rating=1.01), 
  Rating(user=3, product=34, rating=0.99), 
  Rating(user=3, product=45, rating=0.98)))]
```

I'm have been unable to find any example of using map lambda etc to work with this kind of named data.
Ideally, I would like the output to be a dataframe in the following format:

```
User    Ratings
1       3,0.99|4,0.91|9,0.68
2       11,1.01|12,0.98|45,0.97
3       23,1.01|34,0.99|45,0.98
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.  Note the number of ratings is variable and not just 3.

Comment: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html could help  for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RDD defined as

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    (1,
        (Rating(user=1, product=3, rating=0.99), 
        Rating(user=1, product=4, rating=0.91),  
        Rating(user=1, product=9, rating=0.68))),   
    (2, 
        (Rating(user=2, product=11, rating=1.01), 
        Rating(user=2, product=12, rating=0.98), 
        Rating(user=2, product=45, rating=0.97))), 
    (3, 
        (Rating(user=3, product=23, rating=1.01), 
        Rating(user=3, product=34, rating=0.99), 
        Rating(user=3, product=45, rating=0.98)))])
```

you can `mapValues` with `list`:

```
df = rdd.mapValues(list).toDF(["User", "Ratings"])

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- User: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- Ratings: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- user: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- product: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- rating: double (nullable = true)
```

or provide schema:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, "struct<User:long,ratings:array<struct<user:long,product:long,rating:double>>>")


df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- User: long (nullable = true)
#  |-- ratings: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- user: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- product: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- rating: double (nullable = true)
# 

df.show()
# +----+--------------------+
# |User|             ratings|
# +----+--------------------+
# |   1|[[1,3,0.99], [1,4...|
# |   2|[[2,11,1.01], [2,...|
# |   3|[[3,23,1.01], [3,...|
# +----+--------------------+
```

If you want to drop `user` field:

```
df_without_user = spark.createDataFrame(
    rdd.mapValues(lambda xs: [x[1:] for x in xs]),
    "struct<User:long,ratings:array<struct<product:long,rating:double>>>"
)
```

If you want to format the column as a single string you have to use `udf`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf                                                                 
def format_ratings(ratings):
    return "|".join(",".join(str(_) for _ in r[1:]) for r in ratings)


df.withColumn("ratings", format_ratings("ratings")).show(3, False)

# +----+-----------------------+
# |User|ratings                |
# +----+-----------------------+
# |1   |3,0.99|4,0.91|9,0.68   |
# |2   |11,1.01|12,0.98|45,0.97|
# |3   |23,1.01|34,0.99|45,0.98|
# +----+-----------------------+
```

How "magic" works:

- Iterate over array of ratings

  ```
  (... for r in ratings)
  ```
- For each rating drop the first field and convert remaining to str

  ```
  (str(_) for _ in r[1:])
  ```
- Concatenate fields in rating with "," separator:

  ```
  ",".join(str(_) for _ in r[1:])
  ```
- Concatenate all rating strings with `|`

  ```
  "|".join(",".join(str(_) for _ in r[1:]) for r in ratings)
  ```

Alternative implementation:

```
@udf                                                                 
def format_ratings(ratings):
    return "|".join("{},{}".format(r.product, r.rating) for r in ratings)
```

Comment: If downvoting, please comment to help author and other users understand what could be improved

Comment: Final question for bonus points..  How would I go about adjusting the precision of the rating from 0.987 to 0.9  ??   I figured it would be something to do with the schema near the beginning, but actually, the line:  `df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, "struct<User:long,ratings:array<struct<user:long,product:long,rating:double>>>")` doesn't seem to work for me.  I used rdd.toDF() before.

Comment: You could use format  `"{},{:.1f}".format(r.product, r.rating)`